# FlatList inside ScrollView doesn't work in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

When I'm using FlatList inside ScrollView I'm getting an error as VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

I have tried to add the Components as mentioned below:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <ScrollView>
    <View>
      <FlatList />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: May I know why you are implementing the FlatList Component inside the ScrollView Component?

Comment: I have one more list to be displayed below the first FlatList component. So I want total page to be inside a parent ScrollView component.

Comment: We can use the ListFooterComponent to show the children at the end of the flat list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way instead of using Flatlist inside Scrollview like

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      ListHeaderComponent={ContentThatGoesAboveTheFlatList}
      ListFooterComponent={ContentThatGoesBelowTheFlatList} />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Thank you. Added ListFooterComponent and this works.

Comment: this gives clarity. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-fix-virtualizedlists-should-never-be-nested-inside-plain-scrollviews-warning-3a2a887b4ea0